# Printing image from fashion_MNIST data gives colored image?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, mnist

The well-known fashion_MNIST data set for deep leanring/computer vision is a collection of **greyscale images**[https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist].

This dataset is already available with keras [https://keras.io/datasets].

However, when I loaded the data set in Tensorflow Keras API and tried to print some image. I got **colored images**. I wonder why?
Can anyone please explain. Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(training_images[0])
#print(training_labels[0])
#print(training_images[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the color map.

```
plt.imshow(IMG, cmap='gray')
```

Comment: Yes, I know that but I was curious to know if original images are grayscale and it's printing in colors. I searched https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html for looking at the default value for cmap but couln't completely understand.

Comment: Default color map is viridis and that is a rgba colormap

Comment: Thanks, I guess I need to read more about RGB and RGBA. Image Processing terminology is new to me.

Answer (score 4):

It happens because of **imshow()** method of matplotlib.
By default, it uses **rcParams["image.cmap"] to 'viridis'** due to which we got a colored image. You can see here https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html. 
You can also check these parameters in your terminal by running this code:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 print(plt.rcParams)
```

If we set it to "Greys" then we will get grey image. You can set it by running this code:

```
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'Greys'
```

You can read more about 'viridis' here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

Comment: It's not true as per my knowledge. pixel values for greyscale images are also from 0-255 and that's why we divide by 255 before applying any layer of the network. See: http://www.whydomath.org/node/wavlets/imagebasics.html